# LC-3 check that a number entered is not a duplicate of a previously entered number

Tags: duplicates, lc3

User is to enter a number from the keyboard one at a time up to 5 valid times. The program needs to check that the entered number is not a duplicate of an earlier number, how would I go about checking that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this it would be best if you set up a 'for' loop that counts the number of inputs up to 5. As you get each input from the user store that value in a different register to compare later. When you do the actual comparison you will need to NOT and ADD immediate 1 to one of the numbers. Then add the two numbers together and check to see if they equal zero.

I'll try and give you some sample code without actually writing all of it. Usually the LC-3 is used for ASM learning within universities.

```
.ORIG x3000

MAIN    
AND R1, R1, #0          ; Clear R1

LOOP        
    LD R2, LIMIT
    ADD R4, R1, R2      ; Check to see if we've hit our limit
    BRz END_LOOP

    getc                ; Capture a character and stores it in r0.
    out                 ; Sends the character in r0 to the terminal.

    AND R3, R3, #0      ; Clear R3
    ADD R3, R3, R0      ; Store the user's input into R3 to compare the next time we loop

    ADD R1, R1, #1      ; Increment our loop counter
    BR LOOP             ; Branch to LOOP
END_LOOP

HALT    

; Variables
LIMIT   .FILL x0005     ; Store the value of 5 into our loop limit variable

.END
```